Make a wrapper script that calls awk code with different parameters
I have this code that works great for what I want (from an answer to Print duplicate values from CSV file including occurence count by @AdminBee and thanks btw!):
awk -F'|' '{c[$27]++} END{for (i in c) {if (c[i]>1) print c[i],i}}' input.csv

I need to put this in a separate file (for example, pk_check.awk) and then being able to call it from inside a zsh but passing variables like, for example, separator, column_number, filename and extension, something like
separator=|
column_number=27
filename=input
extension=csv

echo | awk -v x=$separator -v y=$column_number -v w=$filename -v z=$extension -f pk_check.awk

(the code above it's more than an idea and could be incorrect or inefficient)
The idea behind it is that I could have (in the future) more awk "mini-test" generic enough to be called from a zsh script with different parameters and may be even that shell script could receive or process a list of parameters for different files.
But before all this, I have to solve this first! :)
I tried some things to ugly to post here and I really don't understand very well how to modify the .awk file to be generic or how to call it from a shell script.

All those parameters can easily be passed to awk without using -v (besides the column number, which is strictly tied to the specific script and will have to be passed using -v I'm pretty sure), is there a reason why it'd be better to factor those parameters into the awk script instead of simply passing them the usual way? Or, more easily, wrapping a Zsh function around the awk command, which would be more customary?

@kos The column number doesn’t have to be passed with -v. It could be picked up from the environment using the ENVIRON associative array.

Fair enough @Kusalananda, I didn't think of that (though I'd probably still make it a parameter to the script rather than having the script pick it up from the environment in this case)

Hi everyone! thanks for making time to answer.
@kos there is not particular reason why I approach the problem this way more than I am pretty noob with awk and it was what I could think of with what I had. And at the end I think I stick with it because part of me was curious how to do it (meaning pass parameters to a .awk file from another script).
But I saw your answer below and is it great. I agree that for this case is preferably for me to make it a parameter to rather pick it up from the environment, but thanks Kusalananda for remembering me that exist that possibility. brb shortly.

You've mentioned .awk files a couple of times. Unix commands do not have suffixes (.awk, .perl, .sh or anything else). That way you can re-implement a command that was written in awk as perl or ruby or anything else without changing other commands that call it. The time when a file would have a .awk suffix would be if it was a file containing a library of awk functions or similar that are used by commands implemented in awk. So you might have function log(msg) { print msg > "/dev/stderr" } in a file named log.awk and then awk 'BEGIN{log("starting")}' in a command dostuff.

@EdMorton Hi Ed! Thanks for your input. I understand that in Unix and Unix-like operative systems there isn't the need of extensions at least not at the extent that are needed in windows, but I wrote .awk files because I thought that would better represent what I wanted to do, that is basically what you said here in your comment: having a re-utilizable function to call inside the script. But then when I saw Kos solution I thought "well, this works pretty good too" so I when with that (I was a little bit pressed for time too).

If the objective is just generalizing the script and giving it a generic / clean interface, I'd personally wrap a Zsh function around the script instead of messing with it to make it accept common parameters such as separator, filename and extension through -v; the exception being column_number, which would have to be passed through -v anyways:
pk_check() {
    awk \
        -F"${1}" \
        -v cn="${2}" \
        '
            { c[$cn]++ }

            END {
                for (i in c) {
                    if (c[i]>1)
                        print c[i],i
                }
            }
        ' \
        "${3}.${4}"
}

Usage:
pk_check <separator> <column_number> <filename> <extension>

For example:
pk_check \| 27 input csv

You could contrive a method to make the function "accept key / value pairs" such as key=value, but still leveraging positional parameters (and associative arrays); this is a very crude and naive method to pass named parameters to a function, and I'm sure it would break in non-trivial cases, not to mention probably overkill for a wrapper, I'm merely posting it for the sake of completeness:
pk_check() {
    local -A p

    while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        local k=${1%%=*}
        local v=${1#*=}

        p[${k}]="${v}"

        shift
    done

    awk \
        -F"${p[separator]}" \
        -v cn="${p[column_number]}" \
        '
            { c[$cn]++ }

            END {
                for (i in c) {
                    if (c[i]>1)
                        print c[i],i
                }
            }
        ' \
        "${p[filename]}.${p[extension]}"
}

Usage:
pk_check separator=<separator> column_number=<column_number> filename=<filename> extension=<extension>

For example:
pk_check separator=\| column_number=27 filename=input extension=csv


Thanks @kos for your comprehensive response and this new approach. It solves what I was trying to do and I am going to implement it like this.
However I am still a bit curious about how to modify an .awk file to make it "parameterized" and I really what to learn more about it, so I appreciate if you could recommend some reading to do so I can learn a bit more about this great tool. Thanks again for making time to answer.

@Johannes no problem, however to specify the separator through -v you can just pass / override FS (awk -v FS=\| [...]) (I suggest learning everything about FS, OFS, RS and ORS as they're very often overriden to achieve specific things). The column number again, you may pass using -v cn directly (as you probably noticed I replaced $27 with $cn, which means "address field number cn", as opposed to the hardcoded "address field number 27").

@Johannes However I don't think it'd feasible at all to specify a filename using a variable. That surely could be done in Perl, I've never seen that done in Awk. Some Awk guru such as Ed Morton may be able to answer that.

@Johannes As for suggested readings, I wouldn't know what to suggest; I mostly "learned" how to use these tools by looking up stuff online anytime I realized I wasn't able to do something that I needed to do, and I slowly learned them enough to be able to use them as an aid during my daily job. man awk usually has all the answers, and after learning the basics I've always been referring to man pages whenever in doubt (this is true in general, not just for Awk). These days I tend to ask ChatGPT whenever I'm getting my feet wet with something new

@Johannes But please always verify / double check with man pages whatever the thing says, especially when learning new stuff; I'd argue ChatGPT is also a tool that one needs to learn how to use correctly :)

Thanks @kos, I'll keep in mind your advice! Evidently this is the most common and efficient way to do it because I google the other way around and didn't find what I has looking for :) . Just with what you showed me here I already have a lot to play with and get better. Thank you very much!

@Johannes I find that leveraging command line arguments in general is at the very least more usual than not doing it and resorting to parameterizing stuff as variables or writing fully blown scripts in the command line, especially when something is meant to be used as a short one-liner; often the final product is less verbose. I'll bring up Perl because it's the tool I'm most accustomed to, but in Perl something like perl -lane 'print $F[1]' file would be at least four times as long if written without using command line arguments. You're welcome and good luck in your endeavour :)

You can specify a file name using a variable, e.g. do seq 4 > myfile.txt to create some sample input and then do this all on 1 line: fname='myfile.txt' awk 'BEGIN{ARGV[ARGC++]=ENVIRON["fname"]} {print FILENAME, NR, $0}'. The "all on 1 line" part is a shell thing to get the variable into the environment of awk, see how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script for more info and alternatives.

ChatGPT is a reasonable way to get a starting point to solving a problem. It will almost always give you the wrong answer (e.g. it'll probably give you an answer that works in trivial, sunny-day cases but fails, possibly disastrously, for less trivial cases) but it'll give you enough code that you can try to fix it and then ask a question here if you can't figure out how to do so or just want to know what's wrong with it.

For example, I just asked ChatGPT "How do I change every question mark to an ampersand in Unix" and it told me sed -i 's/\?/&/g' filename.txt which has the following problems - a) it's GNU-specific and so will fail cryptically in BSD sed and less cryptically in other seds, b) sed uses BREs, not EREs, so by escaping ? that becomes a regexp repetition metachar instead of literal, c) by not escaping & it remains the backreference metachar instead of literal and so will not change anything, and d) by adding -i it will trash my input file instead of just producing the wrong output.

@EdMorton Thanks for chiming in and for you remarks about the filename thing which I wasn't able to answer. By the way let me be clear, I'm not advocating using ChatGPT to learn stuff (let alone generate stuff that are meant to run in production - at all), all I meant to say is it will generally understand what you want to do and point you "in the right direction"; always verify whatever the thing says using man pages, as I said; your example clearly shows the issues with blindly trusting the thing.

@Johannes Please check Ed Morton's remarks about the filename thing we discussed earlier

@kos understood and I agree with you, I was serious about ChatGPT being a reasonable starting point to getting a solution if you don't know where to begin, it's just not the end point (as we both agree on).

@EdMorton Got you, absolutely. I find being extremely pedantic about requests usually helps with getting a decent response (one could say "you should point ChatGPT in the right direction so that it would point you in the right direction". And not towards a ditch like in your sed example :) but unfortunately that doesn't always work either)

Thank you guys! I can't tag you both but I am reading you comments now after some time (I have been sick) and I am reading all your recommendations, so thank you to take time out your lives to share your knowledge and experience. I personally find all this tools (ed, awk, sed, etc.) extremely fascinating for how powerful they are and how they go unnoticed in this GUI era. I hope one day to get that fine knowledge that will allow me to differentiate between gnu, bsd, posix and not posix versions like Ed does! :) Thank you again @EdMorton, Kos. Have a nice day both.

@Johannes You're welcome!
